# Enabling MFA for AAD User with PowerShell 6.2

Tags: powershell, azure, entra-id

I'm working on a way to enable MFA for AAD / O365 users.  I'm referring to this article from the MS docs:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates

If I install the MSOnline module, import it, and connect-msolservice with PS version 5.1 it works as described.  If I try to do this with PS version 6.2 I get:

```
Connect-MsolService : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is this because PS 6.2 is built on .Net Core and it isn't able to load the libraries for a prior version of .Net that's part of the MSOnline module?

What I'm really after is a way to automate enabling MFA for AAD / O365 users, and I'm thinking about using an Azure Function App with PowerShell.  This seems like good way to knit this together with our ITSM system calling a web hook made available via the Function App.  Obviously there's some the permission and security elements to be worked out to do this.  However, if I can't load the MSOnline module to PS 6.2, which is the PS platform available as a Function App, I don't think it would work to use a PowerShell Function App.

I don't see a way to enable MFA for an AAD user in the graph API, but maybe I'm missing something.  Is there maybe another way to enable MFA for an AzureAD user other than the MSOnline PS module or the web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msonline module is indeed not ready for PowerShell 6:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2018/07/02/how-to-install-the-msonline-powershell-module/
And:
https://www.enowsoftware.com/solutions-engine/powershell-core-is-ga-but-not-ready-for-office-365

However, I think it will be soon. Maybe somewhere these days @Ignite? :)

In answer to your (sub)question, how to enable MFA on AzureAD other than with the module and the webgui. Why don't you use Azure AD Conditional Access? It's fully automated, very secure and even better, made for that purpose.

Comment: We'll be turning on conditional access eventually but were asked to create a way for people to opt-in to it for a bit of time in the run-up period before we turn it on.

Comment: They can do that by default. If they go to aka.ms/mfasetup, they can set it up no matter the policies. Ran this PowerShell script from time to time to check which people already activated MFA to require them to do MFA next time: http://techgenix.com/mfa-powershell/